# Strange clang formatting in mathematical expression

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am wondering how to fix some strange issue I'm getting with `clang-format` and longer math expressions in C++.  Suppose we have the following sample code saved in `test.h`:

```
void TestFunction() {
  int long_int_variable_name = 1;
  int result = (long_int_variable_name + long_int_variable_name) * long_int_variable_name - 1;
}
```

We can format it with the Google style by doing:

```
clang-format -style=google -dump-config > .clang-format
clang-format -i -style=file test.h
```

This yields a rather awkwardly formatted expression for `result`:

```
void TestFunction() {
  int long_int_variable_name = 1;
  int result = (long_int_variable_name + long_int_variable_name) *
                   long_int_variable_name -
               1;
}
```

It looks like it has added a line continuation indent before the second operand to  the multiplication, but has aligned back to the beginning of the line before the second operand to subtraction.  And besides that, why has it even brought the `1` down to a new line?  It looks like it is trying to visually couple the operands tighter/looser based on mathematical precedence, but it's gone overboard.

So the primary questions here are

- Why is clang deciding to format this in a seemingly awkward way?
- How can I get this type of expression to be formatted more cleanly, or what options can I play with to work towards making this look reasonable?

I think something that just line breaks only when the rest of the code can't fit in the current line would be a great starting point.  After that, deciding where to indent could help to refine it.

Comment: You can find all the [Clang-Format Style Options in the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) so you can write your own `.clang-format` file to get whatever behaviour you want (within the capabilities of the tool). Did you read the documentation already? If not; do so.

Comment: Have *you* read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. Of course. In detail. *Several times*. We use clang-format at my workplace and our `.clang-format` file has undergone several revisions and reviews and I am the main author of it. I would be negligent if I had *not* read the documentation carefully and *thoroughly*.

Comment: It is generally preferable that a simple formatting rules (like this) be helpfull for dealing with DIFFICULT code, even if it looks overkill for simple code examples like you have shown. Code formatting that looks "nice" for simple code but is misleading for complicated code is much less useful in the long run.   If you want more sophisticated formatting which (say) looks "nice" for simple code but is  also helpful for understanding more complicated code, then program the rules yourself.  You'll find coding the formatting rule itself will be much more complicated.

Comment: Reading the documentation is a total pain: going through it **one single time** takes ~3 hrs. If there was a 5-minute answer on Stack Overflow and I wasn't the one configuring the .clang-format doc, I'd take that over reading the documentation any day. I'm now almost done reading the documentation...so back to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Short and dirty answer:** there's a trick that works in this case.

```
{
    int result = -d + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
                          cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc;
}
```

If you don't like this, give names to intermediate results of computation.

---

**Where did this answer come from? Is there a better answer?**

With some experimentation, we can find out what clang is doing here.  Let's compare `AlignOperands: true` vs `false`:

```
// AlignOperands: true
{
    int result = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
                     cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc -
                 d;
}

// AlignOperands: false
{
    int result = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
            cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc -
        d;
}

// Note: these examples use IndentWidth: 4, ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
```

In both cases, the second operand to multiplication was indented by an extra indent than the second operand to addition.  So it looks like clang is trying to express the fact that multiplication binds tighter than addition.  And that's not really a problem here.

The problem here is the `d` being placed on it's own line.  Why?

It seems that `clang-format` has decided that since the first operand to the addition spanned multiple lines, there must be a line break after the second operand.  And because the second operand to multiplication got an extra indent, it looks extra strange.

Searching through the [clang-format option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for "operand", "indent", "precedence", "multiplication", etc., does not reveal any related options.  This leaves us with a couple potential approaches.

---

**Option 1**: find some creative trick to write the code so `clang-format` doesn't mess it up.  In this case, switching the order of summands is the trick:

```
{
    int result = -d + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
                          cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc;
}
```

The unfortunate thing about this is that now we are making code-writing decisions based on our formatting tool, which is kind of backwards and leads to confusion (the natural question arises: why is it `-d + x` instead of the simpler `x - d`?).

---

**Option 2**: Another option that often also has the added benefit of increasing code readability is to create names for the intermediate results of computation.  For example:

```
{
    double revenue = price_per_unit * num_units_sold;
    double profit = revenue - cost;
}
```

This can really help readers who would otherwise be asking, what on earth does `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa * cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc` even mean?

---

**Default option**: The final option is too add `clang-format off`, `clang-format on` comments around the block of code in question.  I don't like this as much because it adds a lot of mess to the source code (2 lines for on/off, plus another line explaining why you're turning it off), but it's always an option to consider based upon the context.